# Forked Grails VM exited with error while using with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

Getting this error while starting grails with Tomcat

```
|Running Grails application
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I have **GRAILS_OPTS** set inside startGrails.bat

```
set GRAILS_OPTS=-server -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I have **CATALINA_OPTS** set as an environment variable (since I am working with Tomcat server)

```
-server -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I have also tried setting **_JAVA_OPTIONS** variable as

```
-Xmx2048M
```

I have also tried things like mentioning the VM sizes as arguments and changing the `grails.project.fork` values inside `BuildConfig.groovy` but no luck.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grails is a real memory hog.

After all the changes in the setting and variables, out of which nothing worked, I have decided to close all my application to free up RAM space (specially the Chrome tabs, **which eats most of your RAM**). Then I have started the grails application and it worked.

Comment: This solution worked for me, too, which is weird, since my computer has 16 gig of memory. That's not enough to run Grails and Chrome at the same time? Guess not.